# Hide text on form open show text based on submission result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Firstly I apologize for opening a question that might be seen as basic by some but im learning on my own and SO has helped me a lot when I get stuck, like now.

I have a link that opens a modalbox, I then use some JQUERY and ajax to prevent the modal from closing after user has submitted the form

**Image 1 form BEFORE submit**

[image]

**Image 2 form *AFTER* submit**

[image]

**My Problem**

In image1 the text circled **should NOT be displayed** when modal is opened.

Based on result of form submission the text in image2 should get displayed, either showing:

- Successful submission
- Unsuccessful submission

**HTML FORM**

```
 <div id="inline3" style="width:400px;display: none;">
        <h3>Withdraw</h3>
        <form name="withdrawForm" action="" id="withdraw-form" method"post">
        Amount<br /> <input type="text" name="amount" value="" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Withdraw" name="withdraw" class="buttono" />
        </form>
        <div class="form-feedback">
        Thank You We will Get Back to you 
        </div>
         <div class="form-feedback">
        Ooops....Something Went Wrong
        </div>
       <div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $("#withdraw-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $form = $(this);

    $.post(document.location.url, $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        $feedback = $("<div>").html(data).find(".form-feedback").hide();
        $form.prepend($feedback)[0].reset();
        $feedback.fadeIn(1500)
    })

    });
})
```

*Its probably worth mentioning I am using fancy-box for the modalbox*

If anyone can give me a bit of help on how I can modify my code to achieve the desired result described above it will be greatly appreciated:

Comment: What is `data` at `success` callback of `$.post()` ? What is expected result of `$feedback = $("<div>").html(data).find(".form-feedback").hide();` ?

Comment: Try deleting `<div class="form-feedback">
        Thank You We will Get Back to you 
        </div>
         <div class="form-feedback">
        Ooops....Something Went Wrong
        </div>` on your HTML Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel Thank you for your very detailed answer, but for this specific problem, I managed to solve it by simply adding `display:none` to my div in my form. Thus when form is opened user doesn't see the message but after form is submitted `display:none` gets overwritten and message gets displayed

Answer (score 2):

The message showing on the first message was caused by your html code

```
    <div class="form-feedback">
    Thank You We will Get Back to you 
    </div>
     <div class="form-feedback">
    Ooops....Something Went Wrong
    </div>
   <div>
```

after the form.

And change your `$feedback`

```
$feedback = $('<div></div>').html(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your major concern is based on controlling the display of the confirmation message (or any other callback events) on form submission. Hence, we can look at your problem and attack them through a series of small steps.

- Step 1. We should place focus on the "form submission state",
  understanding the events firing before and after when you press
  submit to a form.
- Step 2. Altering the states (thru CSS) of your confirmation message
  block / or other callback events/actions you want to implement.
- Step 3. Structure the confirmation message block for the web view
  (i.e. setting up the HTML divs for displaying the message after state
  alteration).

Let's tackle Step 1 first,

You can create a "Submit Handler" function to handle the form submission states, with something like this:

```
    // Ajax form submission                  
            submitHandler: function(form)
            {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit(
                {
                    beforeSend: function()
                    {
                        $('sample-form button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
                    },
                    success: function()
                    {
                        $("#sample-form").addClass('submitted');
                    }
                });
            }
```

Step 2, as you can see previously, we have assigned a "submitted" CSS class for the callback when the form is successfully submitted. The ".ajaxSubmit" methods allow you to gather information from the form element to determine how to manage the submit process. You may look up for more details at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

So now we have to setup the "initial" and "submitted" states CSS codes to interact with your callback function.

```
    /* initial state */
.sample-form .message {
    display: none;
    }

    /* submitted state */
.sample-form.submitted .message {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    background: transparent;
    font: 300 18px/27px 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

And finally in Step 3, we setup the HTML form codes and message sections to conform with the display logic we have setup in our javascript code.

```
<!-- Sample Form-->
            <form action="sample-form-process.php" method="post" id="sample-form-1" class="sample-form">

                <fieldset>                  
                    <section>
                        <label class="input">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name">
                        </label>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        // next form input field...
                    </section>

                </fieldset>

                <footer>
                    <p class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit">Fill the form to download!</button>
                    </p>

                </footer>

            <!-- Your Message Block -->
                <div class="message">
                    <p>Thank you for your info! Bla bla bla...</p>
                </div>

            </form>         
            <!-- End Sample Form-->
```

Notice how we have appended a "submitted" class to our sample form after success callback of form submission, and how we used CSS to distinct ourselves from the "hide" and "display" states of our message. Finally, using a "div" to hold our message block for web view.

Hope this helps in providing you a better way of thinking and problem-solving skills in handling events with AJAX forms.